# What is /tmp/goc-build-xxxxx directory？

Tags: go

When I use dlv to debug my application, I found that my application is built from `/tmp/goc-build-7e5b20ef452c/`, and my source code directory is `/git.company.com/service/`.

Further, When I exec `cd /tmp/goc-build-7e5b20ef452c/`, the terminal prompts me
`No such file or directory`

I run my application after `go build /git.company.com/service/`

Comment: go build builds in a temporary directory. Nothing to see there, it's, well, temporary.

Answer (score 1):

[`go build`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies) will use [`go env GOTMPDIR`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b7d3f4c0b2f421c6b7bf6ce3533f1b34b470b39d/src/cmd/go/internal/work/action.go#L227) as a temporary folder for building.
If `go env GOTMPDIR` is empty, it falls back to `$TMP` (or `%TMP%`/`%TMPDIR%` on Windows)

Since it is a temporary folder, it is [cleaned up at exit](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/b7d3f4c0b2f421c6b7bf6ce3533f1b34b470b39d/src/cmd/go/internal/work/action.go#L245).